# Tcl to MIPS Machine Code

Tags: assembly, tcl, mips, machine-code

I am trying to generate MIPS machine code out of Tcl script, however, up until now I haven't found any tools that can do that even to other processors. As fas as I know, Tcl has [*Tcl Assembly Language* (TAL)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/2561) which produces stack-based CISC, but this output is not applicable for me. Any other options and solutions ?

Answer (score 1):

Converting Tcl code to machine code (via LLVM) is a current project that a friend and me are working on; the project concerned is [tclquadcode](https://chiselapp.com/user/kbk/repository/tclquadcode/timeline). I've no idea if MIPS is a supported target, or if cross-compilation is practical (we're looking more at JIT as our key use case).

***However…*** You might be better off looking at ways of packaging Tcl code into an executable (e.g., constructing a [starpack](http://wiki.tcl.tk/3663)) so that you get the single-file benefits of compilation without depending on stuff that is frankly still very much only research-grade software. Sometimes it is necessary to take a step back from the problem you're looking at and instead work from a different perspective that takes you to where you're really aiming to go.

Comment: As far as I know, people run Tcl Interpreter on their machine and that Tcl interpreter just executes the code. But to do that you need (modern) machine that has an OS and has C library (because Tcl needs it) CMIIW. 

In my case I am just allowed to have simple processor to run Tcl code (because the system code is written in Tcl). Is it possible for me to write my own compiler for this ? like generating binary machine code for it ?

p.s : I haven't take any classes or courses related to compiler.

Comment: Writing a compiler is extremely difficult.  What you want to look into is cross compiling for your platform.  Cross compiling will enable you to build an executable for a mips target using an x86 platform.   Setting up the tools for cross compilation can be difficult.

Comment: Tcl really doesn't require vast amounts of resources to run. It's target platform is a bit bigger than the 1MB machines I remember using at university, but it's trivially small by comparison with modern desktop systems.

Comment: Which one is easier between using cross compilation and writing my own compiler ? I haven't found any compiler that works compiling Tcl into compilable C program and neither cross compilers that targets single cycle MIPS.